# How can I make a string only use numbers and letters and certain symbols?

Tags: php

I use PHP.

Example:

```
$string = "Hello world!";
if(!safeString()){
   setBlocked(true);
}

function safeString(){
//check string        
}
```

In safeString() I want to check the these following qualities:

The string **can only** have:

- Letters
- Numbers
- Only these symbols (!@#$%^&*/)

If it contains any other non-allowed character, it will be blocked.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
function safeString($input){
   if( preg_match("/[^0-9a-zA-Z!@#\$%\^&\*\/]/",$input) ) return false;
   return true;
}
```

Be careful with accented characters (áéíóú) and stuff like that, if you want them in, you could modify the preg_match first param as:

```
"/[^0-9a-zA-Z!@#\$%\^&\*\/áéíóú]/"
```

if you wan spaces to be allowed you could add "\s":

```
"/[^0-9a-zA-Z!@#\$%\^&\*\/\s]/"
```

And so on...

Some more help here: [PhpRegExp](http://www.noupe.com/development/php-regular-expressions.html)

Comment: Accepted as answer. Thank you!

Comment: Keep in mind that \s includes all white space characters, including tabs (\t) and new lines (\n).